# How to automate execution of commands in separate terminals?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, command-line, execute-command

I am new to LINUX operating system. I am using [ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/) (Robotic Operating System) where I type few commands in **separate terminal windows** for doing the setup.

ie Before I run my program, I have to do (**each in separate terminal**):

```
~$ roscore 

~$ rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone
velodyne_pointcloud/CloudNodelet

~/Desktop/OpenCV$ source setup.bash 

~/Desktop/OpenCV$ rosrun pcl_tutorial
front_view_bag input:=/velodyne_points

/media/BE8C6D3A8C6CEDF9/Users/KARTHICK/Desktop/project/ros_datas$
rosbag play file2.bag
```

The above commands are a must before I can actually run my C++ program and it is to be in the above order, issued from the respective directories.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
Is it possible to write a program or something so that **if I run that single program, all the above commands will be properly executed in separate terminals at the respective directories** rather than manually executing them each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a shell script, to do so, open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`touch daily-script.sh`

Now we need to edit this file contents

`xdg-open daily-script.sh`

Next copy paste the below code to your file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME
xterm -hold -e "roscore" &
xterm -hold -e "rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone velodyne_pointcloud/CloudNodelet" &
cd $HOME/Desktop/OpenC
xterm -hold -e "source setup.bash; rosrun pcl_tutorial front_view_bag input:=/velodyne_points" &
cd /media/BE8C6D3A8C6CEDF9/Users/KARTHICK/Desktop/project/ros_datas
xterm -hold -e "rosbag play file2.bag"

exit 0
```

Once you save the file open a Terminal and type:

`chmod +x daily-script.sh`

Finally your file is executable, to run it:

`./daily-script.sh`

Comment: I did exactly as you said... and  get a terminal window in which the first command **roscore** is being executed... when I do **ctrl+C** it closes and another window having second command opens... **They are not executing simultaneously** ...which is what I want as I mentioned in my question... the commands start a process which depends on the previous one...so the order is necessary and they are executed simultaneously in separate terminal windows normally.

Comment: I tried the edited answer... Now the commands execute in separate terminals simultaneously as I wanted... **But the fourth command is not executing**... This command runs the executable for a program *front_view_bag* .The executable is located by  doing **source setup.bash** in the ~/Desktop/OpenCV/ directory  allowing all packages in this path to be found by ROS..

Comment: @KARTHIK I updated my post

Comment: Thank you @efthialex...Its working now... Can you provide me some links to learn about shell scripts...

Comment: Well I had bought a book called _Pro Bash Programming: Scripting the Linux Shell (Expert's Voice in Linux)_. **Publication Date:** October 19, 2009 | **ISBN-10:** 1430219971 | **ISBN-13:** 978-1430219972. You can find this book on **Amazon**. Also google `learn shell scripts` and you will find some useful resources.

Comment: @KARTHIK start from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting).